# Which JavaFx 2.0 class can cointain different Node implementations like ImageView or MediaView?

Tags: java, javafx-2

The use case is quite simple - I need to create a 'container' which can display (contain) different  subtypes of `Node` class. I will use this object in my `Scene` and switch displayed content on runtime. So when it is displayed first it will contain `ImageView`, after animation finishes I want to swich to `MediaView`, and so on...

Just think of a JavaScript Slider and you will get what I want :)

The question is - is there any component in JavaFX JDK which will help me achieve what I want? I couldn't find any in documentation reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use simple `Pane` and change views by:

```
Pane container = new Pane();
container.getChildren().add(imageView);

...
// event happened
container.getChildren().clear();
container.getChildren().add(mediaView);
```

Also you can try to use `Accordion` control or `TabPane` control.